# Why has my Neewer NW670 suddenly stopped firing on my Canon 5D Mark II?

Tags: canon, flash, troubleshooting

It has been working all these years, and now suddenly it stopped working about half an hour into the shoot. I have tried:

- Checking whether the flash bulb and capacitor are ok by pressing the pilot button on the flash and it fires.
- Making sure that it is mounted correctly.

But still it does not flash. I really need someone’s help to figure out what is wrong.

I'm using the camera in full auto mode, with the flash in TTL. I've used it this way for years, without any issue.

I've used it in darker rooms, so it's not a matter of auto mode thinking it's not dark enough to require flash.  When I change flash settings on the camera the changes get reflected on the flash's settings, too.

If I set the camera in M mode, with the shutter speed at 1/180s and the aperture around f/11 with the flash in TTL, it still does not flash.

I always remove the flash when I'm not using it and reattach it when there's a shoot. It's making the usual noise indicating that it connected, but just fails to fire.

Comment: What are the settings in camera? Have you tried other flash units to see if any of them work?

Comment: Hmm I have using the fully automatic mode the green mode, so apparently it does not let me set anything related to flash

Comment: Ohh and in the flash it’s TTL mode

Comment: How bright is the light in which you are shooting? is it possible that in "green box" exposure mode and TTL flash mode the camera doesn't think you need any additional light from the flash?

Comment: I have tried in a bit darker room it still does not flash

Comment: Is a fast shutter speed selected? Cameras can't sync flash if the shutter is not fully open. Also look for broken contacts, and try shorting the contacts on the hot shoe of the flash with an *insulated* wire (potential HV shock hazard), triggering the flash, to see if the issue is in the camera or the flash.

Comment: Hmm I am using full auto mode

Comment: Also one more thing I noticed that when I change flash settings in the camera then it does get reflected on the flash settings to. Which means contact is not the problem?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Most Canon cameras, including the 5D Mark II, will not allow shutter speeds shorter than flash sync speed to be set if the flash is detected by the camera and not already set to HSS (which requires that the flash supports HSS).

Comment: @SomeGuyWhoCodes What happens if you set the camera in "manual exposure mode" and set the shutter speed to 1/180 second and set the aperture to around f/11 while leaving the flash set in TTL mode?

Comment: There are separate contacts for camera info and for flash trigger (the central button).

Comment: @MichaelC tried and no change , still it does not flash. Btw I have been using the flash more than a year without making any specific setting and using it in full auto.

Comment: @SomeGuyWhoCodes When is the last time you removed and reinserted the flash in your camera's hot shoe? Does your camera indicate that it even detects a flash is in the hot shoe?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If the data contacts are not properly aligned the camera won't usually detect the flash if the pin under the ground rail springs has gotten loose.

Comment: Always the flash is removed and kept and the day the shoot is then it’s attached. And the day it went blank , it was working for atleast 30 mins and then all of a sudden stopped firing.

Comment: Also as I said earlier when I place the flash on the camera it does make usual noise indicating that it connected, but just fails to fire.

Comment: Can you add an image of the LCD display of the flash? Do you see an S1 or S2 displayed on the LCD?

Comment: I can add, after sometime since I am at work atm. But I do see S1 and S2 when I change the mode

Comment: Here is the image and a video https://photos.app.goo.gl/g72cyKhtiEqbgvHc7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication and flash trigger usually go by different contacts since communication uses some sort of serial protocol (these days) while the trigger is very time-critical.  Maybe your camera's flash shoe has lost contact or the trigger circuitry is broken?  What happens with a different camera?  What happens with a different flash?

Comment: I have yet to try with other flash. Still trying to find one.

Comment: So apparently my flash is gone bad, I tried with new flash and it works.